# SUPER data type parsing when import data from S3 to Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a csv file in which there is 1 column with nested format. Something looks like this:

| id | type | detail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | free | {"type":{"limits":{"account":10,"sub":{"term":"month"},"campaigns":{"act":10}}}}} |

I want to load this file stored in S3 into Redshift and use **"SUPER"** as the data type for **detail** column.

The query i'm using is:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(id smallint
type varchar(10)
detail super)
diststyle auto
```

and here is the copy statement (in [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/ingest-super.html), there's not much mentioned about parsing data to super type):

```
copy stage.test
from 's3://.../test.csv'
region 'us-east-1' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/redshift-role'
ignoreheader 1
format CSV 
;
```

i could load the data alright, but the SUPER column doesn't seem to be parse correctly. The result in that column looks like a string and i can't unnest it to query the components.

Could someone please tell me where i went wrong?

Comment: Hey John, I have the same problem, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @HovanesGasparian sorry, i missed your question. Yes the copy command actually works. It was just that i made mistake querying the data. I could query using this format: select distinct charge_schedule, charge_schedule.price, charge_schedule.currency, charge_schedule.period 
from stage.test-table ; (charge_schedule is the column with super type)